# Struct - remove one of the elements

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
struct object {
    char *name;
    struct object *next;
};
```

Using that I can easily create a table as a described in K&R C book. And remove all the objects by that:

```
object *object_destroy(object *obj)
{
    if (obj != NULL) {
        object_destroy(obj->next);
        free(obj->name);
        free(obj);
        obj = NULL;
    }
}
```

But what I want is to remove *one* of the objects in table, **saving all the others**. I really have no idea how to implement that, because just free() that object is won't work: the objects *after* it will be permamently lost. I can't obj_to_remove = obj_to_remove->next too, because after that I will lose all the objects *before* that object.

So can you point me out what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Pick the object **before** the one you want to delete (say `pPreviousObject`). Save `next` pointer of object you want to delete (`pNextObject`). Delete object you want then assign `pPrevious->next = pNext;`. That's done. As you can see, because you have a single linked list, you have first to iterate through all elements until you find the one you want to delete (so you know it's predecessor too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively attempting to delete a single `node` from a *singly linked list* (as opposed to a doubly-linked-list, or a circular list, also known as a ring buffer).

Please refer to the references below for more information on the concept of a singly linked list. In short, you:

1. Start at the first node in the list (the `head` node).
2. Cycle through the list one node at a time, keeping a pointer to the previously accessed node, until you find the node you want to delete.
3. Point the previous node in the list to the one ahead of the current/found node.
   3.1. If there is no node afterwards (we are at the end of the list), set to NULL.
   3.2. If the head/first node was the one found, set the `head` node to the second node in the list.
4. Delete the elements inside the node if the node has been found.
5. Delete the current node itself.

The second reference will be very helpful to you, as it covers building a list from scratch, adding items to the end of the list (appending), inserting items at an arbitrary point in the list, deleting individual items, and clearing out the whole list.

**References**

---

1. *Deleting from a Linked List*, Accessed 2014-04-22, [`<https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/linked-list/delete/>`](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/linked-list/delete/)
2. *Singly linked list - insert, remove, add, count source code*, Accessed 2014-04-22, [`<http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/singly-linked-list-insert-remove-add-count>`](http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/singly-linked-list-insert-remove-add-count)

Answer (score -1):

You have the following 1->2->3->4->5 and you want to remove the element 3. The final result will be 1->2->4->5.

To do this you just need to do the following steps:

1- If the element is in the middle of the list:

- Traverse the table, for each element you save previous element and the element itself.
- When the element equals the one you want to delete you have cur_el = 3 and prev_el = 2. (cur_el and prev_el are pointers to the elements 3 and 2)
- Now just make prev_el->next = cur_el->next (don't forget to keep a pointer to the prev_el.
- Finally just free the cur_el.

2- If the element is the first of the list (let's say you want to delete 1):
- Set the first list element as cur_el->next (here cur_el points to 1, the first element in the list)

- free the cur_el

3- If the element is in the end of the list (in this case 5):
- go to the last element, get the penultimate element (let's call the pointer to this one prev_el)

- set prev_el->next = null
- free cur_el

Also, notice that removing an element from the list has a complexity of O(n), where n is the number of elements of the list.
If you just insert and remove from the begin or from the end you can reach a O(1).

Answer (score -2):

In the question, the memory structure is referred to as a 'table'.  Perhaps it would be better to call it a 'linked-list'.

```
int object_destroy(
      object **head, /* The head of the linked-list is required in order to maintain proper list nodes linkage. */
      object  *obj
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;

   /* Unlink the node to be destroyed. */
   if(*head == obj)  /* Is the obj to destroy the head list node? */
      *head = obj->next;
   else 
      {
      object *temp = *head;

      /* Find the parent list node (to the one that will be destroyed). */
      while(temp)
         {
         if(temp->next == obj)
            break;

         temp=temp->next;
         }          

      /* Not found? */
      if(NULL == temp)
         {
         rCode=ENOENT;
         fprintf(stderr, "obj node not found in list\n");
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      /* Unlink the node, and patch the list so that remaining nodes are not lost. */
      temp->next = temp->next->next;
      }

   /* Free the node to be destroyed. */
   if(obj->name)
      free(obj->name);

   free(obj);

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: @Dogbert goto is a perfectly acceptable( and in some ways only ) option in this case.

Comment: @Dogbert, you are correct that there is almost never a good reason to use it.  However, it is considered good practice to use it for error recovery (and perhaps some implementations of state machines).  It is interesting that academia has been so brainwashed to react exactly as you have.  30+ years of C coding has taught me that code maintainability is better served by this method of error handling, rather than a more nested method.  It also allows for a single 'return' statement (which is also preferable in enterprise quality code).

Comment: I use `goto` statements in stack development and on low power chips where every cycle counts. It has no place in simple application level code like that above.